# In a Chef recipe, how do you specify a particular patch level for a Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra

I'm working with someone else's chef recipe and it consists of these references to the process of installing `1.9.3p0` on my server:

```
package 'ruby1.9.3'
package 'ruby1.9.1-dev'

# set ruby 1.9 to be default
execute 'update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1'
execute 'update-alternatives --set gem /usr/bin/gem1.9.1'

ohai "reload" do
  action :reload
end
```

I'm new to chef so I'm not sure where these packages reside, but seeing no other reference them to them in the repo of recipes, I'm guessing it's referring to a central repo. In that case, how could I modify this recipe to get chef (solo) to prepare my servers with a different patch level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_package.html) may clear things up a little here:

> `package` tells the chef-client to use one of sixteen different
>   providers during the chef-client run, where the provider that is used
>   by chef-client depends on the platform of the machine on which the
>   chef-client run is taking place

So on Debian-based systems like the one that recipe was written for, Chef will automatically resolve the `package` resource to an `apt_package` resource, which will call `apt-get` to install `ruby1.9.3`.

Now, given none of the mainstream Linux distros or FreeBSD package up multiple patchlevels of Ruby (and, in some cases, stated patchlevels are not what they seem), you probably don't want to use `package` to get Ruby. Most likely you'll end up wanting to build it from source using something like [the `bash` resource](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html#bash).

`package` will still be useful for installing the Ruby prerequisites, which you can use from your vendor's package repository without issue.

Comment: I would strongly suggest *not* using the `bash` resource to install Ruby. Instead, depend on one of the pre-baked cookbooks for [RVM](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm), [rbenv](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/rbenv), [chruby](https://github.com/Atalanta/chef-chruby), or something like [this](https://github.com/cassianoleal/cookbook-ruby2).